# How to create multiple p:confirm dialogs on a single page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a need to ask for two different types of confirm dialogs on a single XHTML page using Primefaces. The current example in the Primefaces showcase is very basic. Here is what I have as a basic example:

```
<h:form id="mydatatableform"> 
<p:dataTable ... />
    <p:column ... headerText="Column A Data">
        <h:outputText ... />
    </p:column>
    <p:column ... headerText="Acknowledge Docs">
        <p:commandButton value="Acknowledge" ...
            <p:confirm ajax="true" header="Confrimation" message="Do Acknowledge you have received the docs?"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
    <p:column ... headerText="Accept or Deny">
        <p:commandButton value="Accept or Deny" ...
            <p:confirm ajax="true" header="Confrimation" message="Do you Accept or Deny the proposal?"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<p:confirmDialog id="yesno" global="true">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </h:form>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

The good news is this works just fine.

Unfortunately, The users DO NOT want Yes No for options in the dialog box for the Accept or Deny question. They want Accept or Deny in the dialog box.

I cannot find any good examples of how to have two different confirmDialog options or a way to pick from one or the other.

Ideally the second confrimDialog would look something like this:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="acceptdeny" global="true">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Accept" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="Deny" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </h:form>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

I am sure I need to remove the global=true and somehow reference each confirmDialog seperate in each p:confirm tag but I just cannot find a good example to do this and as I say the Primefaces showcase documentation is not very detailed on this point.

Any advice?

Comment: Check the PrimeFaces documentation… it is in there…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at page 120 of the PF documentation here: [user guide 5.2](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf)

So instead of referencing `<p:confirm>` in the command button of your example, you will show() the relevant confirm dialog.

Here is the excerpt from the documentation I am referring to.

```
<h:form>
  <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('cd').show()" />
  <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure about destroying the world?"
     header="Initiating destroy process" severity="alert"
     widgetVar="cd">
     <p:commandButton value="Yes Sure" actionListener="#{buttonBean.destroyWorld}"
       update="messages" oncomplete="PF('cd').hide()"/>
     <p:commandButton value="Not Yet" onclick="PF('cd').hide();" type="button" />
  </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```